# Pass loadBalancerSourceRanges parameter with istioctl

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-elb, istio

I want to deploy Istio's demo application and pass a source range to the load balancer with the following command:

```
istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo --set values.gateways.istio-ingressgateway.loadBalancerSourceRanges={"x.x.x.x/x"}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Error: failed to apply manifests: validation errors (use --force to override):
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []json.RawMessage
```

How can I pass the parameter in the correct format (ZSH as shell)?

Comment: Hi, what version of istio do You use?

Comment: I am using Istio 1.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the index of the array directly and in ZSH you have to escape the square brackets.

The working command now looks like this:

```
istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo --set values.gateways.istio-ingressgateway.loadBalancerSourceRanges\[0\]=x.x.x.x/x
```